# Colocar limite en relacion uno a muchos php laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

estoy haciendo una app en laravel, pero llegue a una situacion en donde la relacion de la DB es de uno a muchos usuarios - articulos, entonces mi problema es que quiero colocar un limite que los usuarios solo puedan agregar max 5 articulos, he estado buscando, pero nada a lo que trato de intentar hacer. se los agradezco

Comment: Si puedes controlarlo a nivel de aplicacion haciendo un count, todo bien. Ahora si requieres controlarlo a nivel de BD, primero definir una unique key por ejemplo (id_usuario, id_articulo, articulo_numero) en una tabla de compras o algo asi y lo segundo, crear un trigger before insert (en la tabla compras) para que valide en que numero va el campo "articulo_numero" si se llego a 5 que no lo inserte o que intente insertar el 5 y con esto reventara el insert por la unique y el error lo controlas en la aplicacion. o en el trigger cuenta los registros y si hay 5 no lo insertes. Bueno ya tu decides

Comment: muy buena respuesta, sabia que podia controlarlo desde la app, pero queria saber como hacerlo desde la DB muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ese tipo de restricciones es mejor trabajarlas en el apartado lógico de la aplicación, cosa que reduces la cantidad de consultas a tu base de datos. Puedes hacer una simple validación con la función `count()` de Laravel:

```
public function store($article) {
    $user = auth()->user(); // un usuario, el logueado por ejm
    if ($user->articles->count() >= 5) { // condición
        return 'Lo sentimos, has alcanzado el máximo permitido (5)' // mensaje
    }
    else {
        // la lógica de tu operación..
    }
```